# Type 'undefined' cannot be converted to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

Have problem in block with - "Type 'undefined' cannot be converted to type 'T' " error in:

```
  removeItem(key: string) {
  this.map[key] = undefined as T ; }
```

// code

```
class PrintMap <T> {
private map : { [key: string] : T } = {};

setItem(key : string, item : T) {
   this.map[key] = item;
}
getItem(key : string) {
    return this.map[key];
}
clear() {
    this.map = {};
}
  removeItem(key: string) {
      this.map[key] = undefined as T ;
  }
print() {
    for (let key in this.map) {
        console.log(key , this.map[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T` and `undefined` are different types.

You should simply use `delete this.map[key]` to remove the entry.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply cast it to `any` which will bypass the type checking:

```
this.map[key] = undefined as any;
```